# How can I access the react node of Ant Design's native table filter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I want to modify the filter dropdown by allowing the default filter option as well as a custom filter option. To do this I'm planning on replacing the filterDropdown node with an Antd `Tab` node, where one tab has the original filter, and the other tab has the custom filter. How can I access the original filter of the table so I can do this? I am using ant design v4.